How to float textbox on the right side before begin the document and ensure the coming texts are wrapped?
Problem
I want to add a fixed preface to my documents as a textbox on the right side like journal articles. I firstly thinking of use \wrapfigure so that the main text will wrapped well. But when I move the textbox to my cls file (here I used \AfterEndPreamble instead), the main text no longer wrapped. How can it be?
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage[alpine,misc]{ifsym}
\textheight=9.0in
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

  \renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2.1in}
\footnotesize
\begin{framed}
\subsection*{Preface}
\lipsum[1]
\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}}

    \AfterEndPreamble{\maketitle}%

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1-4]


\section*{Section 2}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!
